# Custom authentication in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a question. In Struts, I have an Action that deals with user authentication, i.e., I took the user's credentials and used a DAO to validate user credentials. I want to maintain the same setup in Spring. I'm using Spring 3.0.3 RELEASE.

My question is, I've read Spring Security and in there it specifies JDBC backend "Validation" provider. I want to know, how would, if the user clicked "login" that it submits the credentials to my controller to check for valid authentication?

The reason I want to do this that way is that I have a Service that handles user authentication and authorization.

Thanks in advance.

**PS** How do I make some controller secure in Spring?

**PPS** I'm new to Spring

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom authentication provider that implements `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider` like this

```
package com.bzone.example;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;


public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO call custom service or do whatever you want 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        // copied it from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

}
```

one more step is to configure spring security to use this custom authentication provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
        <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    </http>

    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="com.bzone.example.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but I think this goes immediately in the overridden `authenticate()` method and not in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Usually Spring Security handles authentication inside its own code, using your code as strategies (authentication providers, user details services, etc). But you can handle authentication inside your own  code.

In your action's code, when user credentials are correct, you will:

- Create an `Authentication` containing user name and granted roles (you may use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` as a convenient implementation).
- Put it into security context:
   `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);`
- Broadcast the authentication success event using `AuthenticationEventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(...)` (you may autowire it from the context or create a `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` explicitly).
- Redirect user to the secured resource using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(...)`.

Also you need to supply an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```
<bean id = "aep" class = "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
     <!-- Your login page -->
     <property name = "loginFormUrl" value = "/login" />
</bean>

<security:http entry-point-ref="aep">
    ...
</http>
```

However, if you are actually new in Spring, it may be better to avoid such a massive customizations and use the regular Spring Security architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You can write you own validation mechanism for Spring Security. It have to consists of following parts:

- Auth Filter - reads data from request, then call Auth Provider with credentials token (instance of class Authentication)
- Auth Provider - accepts this auth token (filter can create different tokents, and there can be different auth providers, for each token type), and try to authenticate (calling your service, at your case). After auth you may (or may not) call User Details Service or fill all user data right there
- User Details Service - load signed in user details from somewhere (from jdbc, other service, etc)

Comment: Ok, Seeing that I'm a newbie @ Spring, how would I do this?

Comment: @The Elite: It's not about your case.

Comment: @axtavt: The Elite said that he need to authenticate users using an separate Service. If this is true, then he have to write at least his own Auth Provider. Or i misunderstood something?

Comment: Exactly @splix. Is there a tutorial that can show me exactly the step by step procedures you've mentioned?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman sorry to wake up 2year old thread , did you find any tutorial that shows how to implement Auth Provider

Comment: @Sudhakar, we have moved out of Spring, so I can't be able to help you at this moment. Sorry.

Comment: I have also been looking for one simple and clear tutorial, but it seems there is none about making your own authentication provider.